# MAP estimation (predictive distribution)

Tags: machine-learning

Yes, this is an old exam question but unfortunately I can't find any solution.

*Suppose that you are a part of a team that has trained n temperature prediction models. The models use readings from a set of sensors that measure weather conditions on a given day and predict the temperature for the following day. The i-th model is fully determined by a vector of
parameters wi and estimates the conditional probability P(y | x, wi) of observing temperature y if the sensor state is x. Furthermore, based on historical data your team has a prior belief over
the models given by P(wi) = 2i/(n(n+1)) for i ∈ {1, . . . , n}.
Given that the measured sensor state today is x* please write down the predictive distribution P(y*| x*) for the temperature tomorrow using MAP estimation.*

We didn't really cover predictive distributions. So for a MAP estimate we would want to estimate the parameters wi on the basis of the observed sensor data x. But how can I fit y in here?

Any hints appreciated :-)